# how to add navigation bar at top of the website in shopify?

Tags: shopify, navigationbar

I’m looking for answers regarding Shopify.how to add navigation bar at top of the website in shopify?? for example: i want to add phone no and email id at top of the website in shopify please help me how to do this ?

Thank in advance !!

Comment: Hi, What theme you are using on your shopify store? Whats your store url ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be highly dependent on your theme - some templates have a space for a message at the top which can be set via the admin, and some templates don't.

For example, the Minimal theme has a setting in Customize Theme->Header called "Top bar text".  Debut has an "Announcement Text" setting in the same place.

If your theme does not have such as facility, and you are willing to modify code, go to Customize Theme->More Actions->Edit Code, then go to Sections->header.liquid, and change that.